# Как передать Event Object в функцию при использовании замыкания?

Tags: javascript, события

К примеру есть код:

```
var figures = document.getElementsByTagName('figure'), i;
for (i = 0; i < figures.length; i++) {
    figures[i].addEventListener('click', (function (i){
        return function () {
            console.log(i);
        };
    }(i)), false);
}
```

Для того, чтобы вывести текущее значение i, используется замыкание. Но как в таком случае передать в обработчик события Event? Ведь следующий код работать не будет:

```
for (i = 0; i < figures.length; i++) {
    figures[i].addEventListener('click', (function (**event**, i){
        **event.preventDefault();**
        return function () {
            console.log(i);
        };
    }(event, i)), false);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не передаете event в eventListener. Это делает браузер, вызывая Вашу функцию со своими параметрами.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_addeventlistener.asp :

> When the event occurs, an event object is passed to the function as
>   the first parameter.

Сделайте `event` параметром функции, которую Вы используете как eventListener.

```
var figures = document.getElementsByTagName('figure'), i;
for (i = 0; i < figures.length; i++) {
    figures[i].addEventListener('click', (function (i){
        return function (evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            console.log(evt.type);
            console.log(i);
        };
    }(i)), false);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, я почему-то думал, что Event может быть только в функции, которая находится непосредственно в addEventListener.